# MySQL error code 1017

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a trigger on one table to insert after on another table. The trigger query seems to be okay to the best of my knowledge, but I'm getting the error:

> Error Code : 1017
>   Can't find file: '.\rtasys\@003cozekimessagein@003e.frm' (errno: 22)

My trigger query is:

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE
/*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
TRIGGER `rtasys`.`on_insert_ozekimessagein` AFTER INSERT
ON `rtasys`.`<ozekimessagein>`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERT INTO ozekimessageout SET ozekimessageout.`receiver`=NEW.sender;
INSERT INTO ozekimessageout SET ozekimessageout.`msg`=NEW.msg;
INSERT INTO ozekimessageout SET ozekimessageout.`status`=NEW.sender;

END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: are table engine identical?.. I ask this questions following this: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,134778,134778#msg-134778

Comment: thankx! the table were not similar plus how i have named the table

Comment: Made similar type to all tables. may be this help. and give the table sources, it will hepl to find the solution

Answer (score 4):

MySQL can't find `ozekimessageout` table definition file (.frm). Try to:

```
REPAIR TABLE ozekimessageout;
```

or recreate table `ozekimessageout`. It's also possible that the file exists but MySQL does not have privieleges to read it. Check that the file `rtasys\@003cozekimessagein@003e.frm` exists and MySQL has rights to read/write/update it.